# How to index Swedish field names in Solr

Tags: solr

I'm indexing Swedish content into Solr, the field names are also in Swedish. But things like `ä` are being normalized to `_` , for instance, the source field name  `Märkspänning_V_sv_s`  is getting normalized to  `M_rksp_nning_V_sv_s`

Is there a way to get around this normalization?

Comment: I am of the opinion that we should be worried about the values of the field and not the field. Anyways, are you building the schema dynamically or schema file is static one?

Comment: If you need to use special characters in the field name (which you _really_ should try to avoid), you can't use the schemaless with the default settings, as that will attempt to convert the field names to safe value. Define the field names yourself, or better, devise a better plan than to rely on non-ascii letters in the field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not to use the special characters name for the field as per your requirement. Avoid it if you can, it would better.

Its better to define the required fields manually by editing your schema.xml file.
Define the appropriate field with required setting like `indexed=true` , `stored=true`, `fieldType` for your field etc.